# Unknown syntax error C#

Tags: c#

I have a constructor for a class below:

```
public void GenericProblem(string _operation, int _problems, int _min, int _max) {
    private static int operation = (_operation || 1);
}
```

I'm getting an error at the opening `{` stating that a `}` is required to close. I can assure this isn't caused by anything outside this because if I remove the variable `operation` the error goes away. Maybe I'm just being stupid but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

`private static` are only valid modifiers for class members. If you want to declare a local variable (local to the method), then just write `int operation`:

```
public void GenericProblem(string _operation, int _problems, int _min, int _max) {
    int operation = (_operation || 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually an `static` variable are used to share its value among all instances of the class.

```
public class Foo
{
    public static int Boo=10;

    public void AddTen()
    {
      Boo += 10;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var f1 = new Foo();
      f1.AddTen();

      Console.WriteLine(Foo.Boo);// Output:20
    }
}
```

So the scope of the `static` field is entire type. That's why you can't declare `static` field within a method. A method has its own scope, and the variables you declared in a method must be inaccessible over the method's border. So you should follow the suggestion of @poke in declare a local variable:

```
 int operation =...;
```

Another thing is you can't apply a logical operator  between an `string` and a `int` (`_operation || 1`). Check this [msdn reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx).